# How can I keep divs centered when resizing a webpage?

Tags: html, css

I'm learning CSS with The Odin Project and I made a mockup of the Google.com homepage. Everything looked perfect until I resized the browser window and the elements move out of place.

I've been trying out many different methods on how to keep the divs (Google logo, search bar, and buttons) centered when the page is resized.

```css
#header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -150px;
  margin-top: -125px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}
#topbar {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
.centered {
  width: 960px
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0.15rem;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #666;
}
.alignleft {
  float: left;
}
.alignright {
  float: right;
}
p {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #7D7676;
}
```

```html
<title>Google</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="google-homepage-css.css">
<!-- Top bar -->

<body>
  <div id="topbar">
    <p align="right"><a href="https://mail.google.com" style="color:#7D7676;text-decoration: none">Gmail</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://images.google.com" style="color:#7D7676;text-decoration: none">Images</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="http://i.imgur.com/xmMdSIp.png">&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <!-- Google Center Image -->
  <div id="centered">
    <div id="logo">
      <img id="header" src="http://i.imgur.com/hs6n5hR.png" width="400">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Search Bar and Buttons -->
  <div id="search">
    <form id="searchbar" width="500">
      <br>
      <input type="text">
      <br>
    </form>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="firstbutton">Google Search</button>
    <button type="button" id="secondbutton">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="footer">
    <p class="alignleft"><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/ads/" style="color:#666;text-decoration: none">&nbsp;&nbsp;Advertising</a>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <p class="alignleft"><a href="https://www.google.com/services/" style="color:#666;text-decoration: none">Business</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <p class="alignleft"><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/" style="color:#666;text-decoration: none">About</a>
        </p>
        <p class="alignright"><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/" style="color:#666;text-decoration: none">Privacy</a>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/" style="color:#666;text-decoration: none">Terms</a>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="https://www.google.com/preferences" style="color:#666;text-decoration: none">Settings&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
        </p>
  </div>
```

---

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/westonludeke/wbehzyqo/)

---

I feel it should be something like this but I'm not sure:

```
div {
    position: relative
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Note: I'll work on resizing and adding colors to the search bar and buttons after, my biggest concern in finding how to keep the search bar and buttons centered under the Google logo when the browser page is re-sized.

Comment: Have you tried this ?
```<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">```

Comment: the google logo is centered regardless of screen size. copy whatever you did for that?

Comment: You can set margin-left/margin-right as "auto", but you need to specify a width of the div to allow the broawser to calculate the margins.

Comment: Do not use `position` property to position elements (yeah, I know...). [display and float](http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/positioning-content/) are more advisable for layout (and mighty Flexbox and in 1-3 years Grid Layout but I don't think it's for beginners). Also search "horizontal centering in CSS" => margin: 0 auto vs text-align: center (for centering itself or its content, roughly)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the property `text-align: center` to your `<div>` ancestor with an id of `#search`.

```
#search{ text-align: center; }
```

This will center the `<input>` and `<button>` elements because they retain their `inline` characteristics.

```css
#header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -150px;
  margin-top: -125px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}
#topbar {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
#search {
  text-align: center;
}
.centered {
  width: 960px
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0.15rem;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #666;
}
.alignleft {
  float: left;
}
.alignright {
  float: right;
}
p {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #7D7676;
}
```

```html
<title>Google</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="google-homepage-css.css">
<!-- Top bar -->

<body>
  <div id="topbar">
    <p align="right"><a href="https://mail.google.com" style="color:#7D7676;text-decoration: none">Gmail</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://images.google.com" style="color:#7D7676;text-decoration: none">Images</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="http://i.imgur.com/xmMdSIp.png">&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <!-- Google Center Image -->
  <div id="centered">
    <div id="logo">
      <img id="header" src="http://i.imgur.com/hs6n5hR.png" width="400">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Search Bar and Buttons -->
  <div id="search">
    <form id="searchbar" width="500">
      <br>
      <input type="text">
      <br>
    </form>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="firstbutton">Google Search</button>
    <button type="button" id="secondbutton">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="footer">
    <p class="alignleft"><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/ads/" style="color:#666;text-decoration: none">&nbsp;&nbsp;Advertising</a>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <p class="alignleft"><a href="https://www.google.com/services/" style="color:#666;text-decoration: none">Business</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <p class="alignleft"><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/" style="color:#666;text-decoration: none">About</a>
        </p>
        <p class="alignright"><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/" style="color:#666;text-decoration: none">Privacy</a>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/" style="color:#666;text-decoration: none">Terms</a>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="https://www.google.com/preferences" style="color:#666;text-decoration: none">Settings&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
        </p>
  </div>
```

---

[**Revised jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/5kqafv6t/)

Answer (score 1):

`<div>` is a block element and by default it takes 100% width of its parent.

If you try to center it using `margin: 0 auto`, then you won't get the expected result. You have to set width in order the margin to be applied.

See an example below:

```css
.parent{
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.item{
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">
    <span>some text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```